# how to return individual php variables to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

How do I access the individual php variables after an ajax call?  I have two variables returned from message.php $id and $messageid and I need to access these from ajax.

In my php I have:

```
if($array1){
$id = "1";
$messageid = $messageid;
}
```

ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#newmessage').on('submit',function(e) {

$.ajax({
    url:'message.php',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    success:function(data){

if($.trim(data) == "1") { <-- this needs to be data.id

$("#message").modal("hide"); <-- this needs to be #message.data.messageid

}
else{
alert("error"); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

In php, you need to return the responses as json format:

```
if ($array1) {
  $id = "1";
  $messageid = $messageid;
}

echo json_encode(array('id' => $id, 'messageid' => $messageid));
```

In Javascript: You need to retrieve the response and parse it as your way.

You should change the `dataType: 'HTML',` into `dataType: 'json',`

Answer (score 0):

use like in php

```
$arr['id'] = "1";
$arr['messageid'] = $messageid;

echo json_encode($arr);
```

In js ajax , use `dataType: 'json'`
In js in success,

Use data.id OR data.messageid.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this apart from json:

In your php file:

```
echo $id."#".$messageid;
```

Now in your ajax success function:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'message.php',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    success:function(data){

    var result=data.split('#');//for splitting id and message
    //result[0] will contain id
    // result[1] will contain msg
    //use result accordingly

}
```

hope it helps...